# Is there a way to search and select between current opened tabs in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: command + p]

In visual studio code, press `command + p`, there is a search input and can search and select files,

but in this list, there are some other items, such as recently opened(don't know the exact rule how they will display there)

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to search and select between currently opened tabs?

Comment: adding irrelevant tags will not help you

Comment: it is disabled in new installs but you can get an `Open Editors` view in the explorer bar

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shows opened editors

[image]

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type `edt` <kbd>Space</kbd>
   and then you can type your desired file name(if needed).

[image]

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> works same as point (2) with pre filled `edt` word.

[image]

4. you can enable(check/tick) open editors from `EXPLORER` Side Bar dropdown menu and it shows Opened editors in `Explorer`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried  "2." and "4. ", these work very well, but "1. " and "3. " didn't work, I'm using macOS Catalina, What's the exact command name of name  "1." and "3. ", could you please go to "keyboard shortcuts" and check the name of those commands?

Comment: 1. Commands 1. "view quick open previous recently used editor in groups"  2. "view show all editors by appearance".

Comment: 2. is exactly what I need, Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Ctrl+Tab` shows only opened editors of **currently focused** group, unlike `Ctrl+K` `Ctrl+P` that searches through **all** opened editors.

Comment: CMD+K CMD+P not working in macos